# How to work in parallel with another dev on Wordpress-based website on local machine

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on WP-based project which is installed on my local machine (Wamp), so the latest version of the database and WP files is on my laptop.
I'm pushing WP files into git repository, so another dev can pull the files from there and push his code into the git as well. Merging of WP files works fine with git, the problem is the database changes. Once another dev changed something is his local database, I had to do the same in my DB to keep my database up to date, which didn't really work for us.

We are trying to use a centralized database on an external server: all the files are stored on our local machines and we connect to the external mysql server using different DB users. It works better in terms of merging of DB changes, since we both change the same database, but we're having troubles if one of us need to install a plugin, as in this case the dev who install the plugin physically have the plugin files on his local machine, but another dev - doesn't have it. As a result we have to add plugin files manually and then one of us just activate the plugin. Another downside of such approach is - we both connect to the external database, so we are loosing time based on a ping to the server each time we need to re-load a webpage during development in comparison to the same action using a local database.

Please describe how do you work on Wordpress-based website in parallel with another devs? Which tools are you using to make development process smooth and to avoid issues I described above?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/.

Comment: @amarinediary Do you mean to push all the files including WP core, uploads and plugins to the github repo? Do you have any advice of how to use a centralized database efficiently? Centralized DB we are using at the moment is self-hosted on VPS server and 'time to first byte' is pretty long in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Performance wised best option is AWS EC2 (Be sure to read on it first it's not friendly at all). Couple-it with AWS CodeCommit/CodeDeploy (linked to GitHub). You can have two branch one stanging and one live, pushing changes to changing then pushing it live.